# Probability of resulting in odd numbered die roll and red suited card?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Roll a die and pick one card from a standard deck.
What is the probability that this procedure will result in an odd numbered
die roll and a red-suited card?

I am guessing 1/4? because odd + black, odd + red, even + black, even + red.

Comment: Your guess is good (assuming there is no joker in the deck!). Now can you formalise your intuition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hunch is right on track. There are an equal number of odd numbers as there are even numbers painted on a fair die. And there are an equal number of red cards as there are black cards in a standard deck of $52$ cards. So the  four outcomes you list are equally likely.

More generally:

$(A)\;$ The probability of rolling an odd number when tossing a die is $\frac 36 = \frac 12$.

$(B)\;$ The probability of picking a red card from a deck of $52$ cards is $\frac {26}{52} = \frac 12$.

Using the rule of the product, the probability of rolling an odd number **AND** picking a red card is $$\frac 12 \times \frac 12 = \frac 14$$

We can use this same approach in more complicated scenarios, like finding the probability that the number resulting from a toss of a tie is a multiple of $3$ and the card drawn from a deck of cards is a queen.